# spliting js code apart (in Ruby'ish way)

Tags: javascript, module

Since i love how easy it is to split code apart in Ruby On Rails, using modules & classes, i Wanted to know, whats wrong/good in splitting js code apart, like this:

```
    var MyApp = {};
    MyApp.db = {};
    MyApp.settings = {};

    // settings.js
    // -------------
    MyApp.settings.get = function () {
        // do some stuff
    };
    MyApp.settings.set = function () {
        // do some stuff
    };
    // -------------

    // db.js
    // -------------
    MyApp.db.init = function () {
        // do some stuff
    };
    // -------------

    $(function () {
        MyApp.db.init();
        MyApp.settings.get();
        MyApp.settings.set();
    });
```

I have read about using prototype, but it doesn't feel as clear as first example.

```
var MyApp = (function (my_app) {

    my_app.init = function () {
        // stuff
    };

    return my_app;
}());

MyApp.prototype.settings = (function (my_app) {

    my_app.get = function () {
        // stuff
    };

    my_app.set = function () {
        // stuff
    };

    return my_app;
});

MyApp.init();
MyApp.settings.get();
MyApp.settings.set();
```

The first example works perfectly on chrome browser (have not tested on others), and seems way more cleaner to me, than prototype and others iv'e seen.. And i could not find any info on something similar to my example, which made me think, why people are not using this..

And i also **realize**, that my example is **not the convention way** of doing things, but **are there any reasons besides that**, why i should not use first example?

EDIT: Main reason, that i like my example, is, that i do not want to initialize MyApp as new object, and i want to split it apart in multiple files.

EDIT2: My main question is, is there any reason, why i should not use first example, besides it not being the 'convention'?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario the second example doesn't offer any benefits. It would be useful if you wanted to declare some functions or variables that shouldn't be exposed neither in the global scope nor as public methods of `MyApp`. Using prototypes also doesn't lend any benefits, because you'll probably only have one instance of `MyApp` (you use it as a namespace, not an object you're going to instantiate using `new` keyword).

For example:

```
MyApp = (function () {
    var my_app = {};

    // calculateSomeStuff  and number are "private" to the methods declared here.
    // you can't call calculateSomeStuff() or change number from outside, 
    // and it's not exposed as MyApp.calculateSomeStuff() or MyApp.number
    var number = 4;
    var calculateSomeStuff = function(){
        var result = /* do some calculations */
        return result * number;
    }
    my_app.get = function () {
        var data = calculateSomeStuff();
        return data + number/2;
    };

    return my_app;
}());
```

Comment: My main question is, is there any reason, why i should not use first example, besides it not being the 'convention'?